# submit button in iframe within parent page

Tags: forms, iframe, submit

I need to submit a button in iframe within parent page.

iframe button:

```
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Search"  id="search_button" />
```

I tried to use this in parent page with no results :

```
 <a href="#" class="btn_search row_right" onclick="document.getElementById('my-iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('search_button').submit()">Search</a>
```

This won't work either :

```
<a href="#" class="btn_search row_right" onclick="document.frames['my-iframe'].document.getElementById('search_button').submit()">Search</a>
```

Comment: Is the frame under the same domain as the parent page? If it isn't, you have no access to it.

Comment: Yes, iframe its on the same domain.

Comment: Are both codes correct? Any thoughts please ?